# Spring Gateway Question on reverse proxying to TLS micro-services

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-cloud-gateway

I am currently working on a project where each micro-service has it's own tls certificate.

I am thinking of using spring gateway to address a cross concerns like csrf (using the double submit pattern).

I would like the gateway to validate the csrf before proxying to micro-services and to create a new csrf value after each response of micro-service and mutate the response to include new csrf values.

Since each micro-service (that the gateway is proxying to) has it's own tls certificate is it possible to read and mutate the request before and after sending it to the micro-services?

I guess I am a little confused on how the gateway would work if it does not have the certificate to read the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway will establish it's own tls connection. After which the gateway will then apply it's filters then proxy to a micro-service establishing another tls connection. In this senario we will have 2 different tls connections (from client browser to gateway, from gateway to service).

In my senario, I had micro-services with self signed certificates. The gateway settings will need to include the public keys for each service to establish a tls connection (since it will not be able to validate the certificate from a certificate authority). Spring gateway allows us to do this within the application properties file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          trustedX509Certificates:
          - cert1.pem
          - cert2.pem
```

Lastly, I was able to validate csrf value within the gateway before proxying to micro-services by creating a filter to do this. I have decided against changing the csrf value every request. For my use case I only needed to generate the csrf once for the user's session (I generated the csrf once after the user signs in).